# How to force `screen` to clear the terminal after commands like `htop`

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, fullscreen

I have recently started using [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) in order to be able to split my terminal vertically and horizontally. However, it does not clear the terminal automatically. For example, when I open a file using `vim` and then I close it, the screen fills the terminal with the content of file. Is there a way to fix it and make it like normal Terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably thinking of the *alternate screen* feature, which allows full-screen applications such as `htop` to display in a different view, and on completion returning to the normal view (without the application showing).  That is the `altscreen` setting in your `.screenrc`, described in the manual:

> **Command:** [**`altscreen`** *state*](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#index-altscreen-123)
>
> If set to on, *"alternate screen"* support is enabled in virtual terminals, just like in xterm. Initial setting is **`‘off’`**.

Comment: It works. There wasn't any `.screenrc` file at the beginning; I created one and put the `altscreen on` in it.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal type

```
clear
```

That should do the trick

Comment: `clear` will clean the screen, but I want the output of previous commands to be there. Let's say I run `htop` and close it, I want the output to be cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> over the dirty screen

Comment: You don't have to do that with a normal Terminal

Answer (score -2):

Normally screen command help to keep our session live irrespective whether you have closed the putty or remote session from your workstation. we can again resume to same screen anytime if we have not detached screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> ).

are you using screen in any script?